# How to move Data from One webapplication site to another webapplication site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions

I have two webapplications and different site collections. I have to move data from One wbapplication site to another.

I used SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges.Data's are moving in webapplication1 to Wepapplication2.

But user does not have permisiion for webapplication 2 But the user able to move data to webapp1 to webapp2.

If I remove SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges user not able to move the data. If I gave permission for webapp2 is able to move.

So I used SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges and it was working in local.

This same funtionality we installed in Client server.
when user move data from webapp1 to webapp2 it was showing **you dont have access to site**.

But it was working in Local sharepoint server.

Client they are having multi server and Webapplication2 is Extented web application

so my doubt is Local sharepoint server it was working But in client server is not working
Why its happening ?

my code:

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               using (SPSite destSite = new SPSite("http://testsite/")) //second webapplication
                   {
                       using (SPWeb destWeb = destSite.OpenWeb())
                       {

```
                       //SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
                       destWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                       if (ContractArea == "UESC BOA Contracts")
                       {
                           destDocumentList = destWeb.Lists.TryGetList("UESC BOA  BP1");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           destDocumentList = destWeb.Lists.TryGetList("BP1");
                       }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

When you are running under the ElevatedPrivledges you are running effectively under application pool account of the iis site. Maybe on client site those 2 applications are running under different application pool account there fore WebApp1 code (appPoolA) doesn't have access to the WebApp2.

Comment: in local my WebApp1 and WebApp2 appPoolA accounts are same.Client system it is different so for this what i can do ?

Comment: You need to grant contribute or admin permission for the AppPoolA in the WebApp2 (either for whole web app through central admin, or through site collection settings)

Comment: Its not possible to get access through code ?

Comment: For example
Wepapp1 - appPoolaccount username - user1
Wepapp2 - appPoolaccount username - user2

so in webapp2 i have to give permission for user1 ?
if yes where should i can give?Wepapp2-->Site settings-->site collection administrator i need to add the user1.?

Comment: Yes it is possible, instead of running with elevated you need to impersonate WebApp2 Pool. Have a look at this example http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/ . Impersonation is best practice anyway, you need to run code under elevated privileges only if you need to work with local filesystem (ie. make modifications to the web.config or create custom log file)

Comment: Re. User1 and User2 exactly that add User1.

Comment: just conform me MAREK if i add user1 to Wepapp2-->Site settings-->site collection administrator  user able to access the Wepapp2 site  right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: i tried i added user1 in site collection admin but still its displaying you dont have access to the site

Comment: i need to add user2 in wepapp1 ?

Comment: Not sure without knowing what you have in code and what message you get in ULS logs. ULS should show you which account is getting access denied.

Comment: i was updated my question with code 
 destWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;(here only error is coming(Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.)